# How to change the cmd window via batch?

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

I want to use batch to make small apps but the size of the window is too large. I can manually change it via properties but that is not what I need for multiple windows.

Is it possible to change the size of a command line window via batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes use this line after title

```
MODE CON:COLS=15 LINES=4
```

example...

```
@echo off
color 0b
MODE CON:COLS=30 LINES=15
ping -t www.google.com
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You could use this code:

```
    MODE CON:cols=x lines=y
```

(x and y are changed to the numbers you want) 
But you could also use:

```
    mode x,y
```

(With x being the columns and y being the lines) 
Which I found to work better than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
mode con cols=x lines=y
```

With x and y the desired number of colums and lines of the console